# Do multiple websocket connections share one TCP connection?

Tags: sockets, networking, websocket, tcp, udp

## Question

Suppose I open websocket connections `/A`, `/B` and `/C` from one client to the same server, and messages are constantly being sent by the client on each ws connection.

If the packet carrying a message for ws connection `/A` times out and ends up needing to be being retransmitted in the underlying TCP layer, is there any chance that this will impact messages being transmitted by the client on ws connections `/B` and `/C`, in the way that multiple packets being sent over a single TCP connection will be delayed when an earlier one times out?

Or is there a chance that each ws connection receives its own TCP connection and so any congestion on one does not impact the packets carrying messages on the others? Could it be implementation-specific?

## Overview

After an initial handshake over HTTP, Websockets send their data over a TCP/IP connection.

My assumptions regarding TCP Connections:

- For a specific TCP connection on a given port, the connection makes the guarantee that all packets sent by the a sender through it will be received by the receiver, and will do so in order. It is a reliable ordered connection.
- This means if two packets are sent over a TCP connection by the sender and the first one does not arrive within a given timeout, the second one is delayed until the first one has been successfully retransmitted by the sender. As far as the receiver is concerned, they always see packet one, then two.
- If you create two separate TCP connections on two separate ports, then packets lost on one connection naturally have no impact on packets on the other connection. The reliable ordered guarantee only applies to the packets within one TCP connection, not all of them.

Since an active websocket connection runs on top of a TCP connection, are there any assumptions we can make when we open multiple parallel websocket connections between the same client and server?

If I have a websocket javascript client opening two or more websocket connections to the same server, does the underlying implementation use only a single TCP connection?

Is there a chance that this may be implementation-specific, or is it simply *guaranteed* that for a given websocket server all connections will occur on the same underlying TCP connection?

---

## Context

The context here is a networked multiplayer game in the browser, where the desired behavior would be to have multiple parallel data streams where any timeout or latency on one stream has no impact on the packets sent on the others.

Of course when low latency is desirable for multiplayer games you generally want to use UDP instead of TCP, but there is no real cross-browser, well supported option currently for that that I am aware of. In an environment where UDP sockets are an option you would implement your own data streams with varying reliability/order guarantees on top of UDP.

However UDP-like low latency when it comes to one packet not blocking another *can* be achieved by guaranteeing that a TCP connection only ever has one packet in flight, and using more connections to allow in-parallel packets ([source](http://ithare.com/almost-zero-additional-latency-udp-over-tcp/)). Naturally that loses out on some optimizations, but may be desirable if latency is the primary variable being optimized for.

Comment: No. Each Websocket has a distinct TCP connection. But if a packet for connection A times out it indicates a problem in the network, and that problem may also cause packets for B or C or both to time out.

Comment: Right, the main benefit I see is less about handling complete packet timeouts (which would normally cluster and happen less on just isolated packets) and more about not having to wait in cases where network jitter causes packet 2 to arrive before packet 1 even if you know one doesn’t depend on the other.

Comment: That being said, could you provide a source or documentation? I don’t doubt the validity of your claim, rather I would like to read up on it properly.

Comment: HTTP/2 supports multiplexing streams over one TCP/IP connection. I think this is also true for WebSockets over HTTP/2.

Comment: maybe you could use WebRTC data channels instead of websockets?